# How to separate the traffic of 3 network interfaces

Tags: networking, network-interface, routing, traffic

How to separate the traffic of 3 network interfaces on Ubuntu 22.04

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.48  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::8276:83ab:72d6:1287  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 9c:53:22:48:77:19  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7797  bytes 1129504 (1.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6828  bytes 593700 (593.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp8s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.101  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::b875:1df4:ff5e:9f09  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d8:5e:d3:01:84:ed  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 135512185  bytes 8949006996 (8.9 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 237  overruns 235  frame 0
        TX packets 365038054  bytes 534261499563 (534.2 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xfa800000-fa81ffff  

enp9s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.36  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 2403:6200:89a6:d09d:5606:aae2:c339:9eb1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2403:6200:89a6:d09d:d5ac:2515:913e:e2be  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::272a:26bd:9d12:e881  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d8:5e:d3:01:84:ee  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 274876935  bytes 23805585708 (23.8 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1956  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 740203694  bytes 1081935809783 (1.0 TB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

enp8s0 already works separately by default, connected through 192.168.0.1
It has been working smoothly with enp9s0 which connected through 192.168.1.1
Then I added eno1 and the problem occurred.

All the network interfaces are connected to different routers which are of 3 different ISPs
eno1 is of additional LAN pcie card while enp8s0 and enp9s0 are of onboard LAN slot

Here is my ip route result

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp9s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp8s0 proto dhcp metric 102 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp metric 103 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp8s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp8s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.101 metric 102 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp9s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.36 metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.48 metric 103
```

Since enp9s0 connected to ISP1, enp8s0 connected to ISP2 and eno1 connected to ISP3

I want the traffics of these 3 to go out separately according to their ISP. When I curl they gone separately

```
money@money:~$ curl --interface enp8s0 ifconfig.me
101.108.144.237
money@money:~$ curl --interface enp9s0 ifconfig.me
14.207.43.37
money@money:~$ curl --interface eno1 ifconfig.me
171.100.22.228
```

But when I use rclone to upload files it stuck

This happened before when I first added enp8s0, before that I only had 1 network interface which is enp9s0 now

I had to

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev enp8s0 src 192.168.0.101 table rt2
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp8s0 table rt2
sudo ip rule add from 192.168.0.101/32 table rt2
sudo ip rule add to 192.168.0.101/32 table rt2
```

and solved it

Now I added eno1 and had the forementioned problem again
So I tried both

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1 src 192.168.1.48 table rt2
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1 table rt2
sudo ip rule add from 192.168.1.48/32 table rt2
sudo ip rule add to 192.168.1.48/32 table rt2
```

and

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1 src 192.168.1.48 table rt3
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1 table rt3
sudo ip rule add from 192.168.1.48/32 table rt3
sudo ip rule add to 192.168.1.48/32 table rt3
```

But still can't make it through

Additional information when ip route list table

```
money@money:~$ ip route list table rt2
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp8s0 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp8s0 scope link src 192.168.0.101 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1 scope link src 192.168.1.48 
money@money:~$ ip route list table rt3
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp8s0 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp8s0 scope link src 192.168.0.101 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1 scope link src 192.168.1.48
```

When cat /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

```
#
# reserved values
#
255 local
254 main
253 default
0   unspec
#
# local
#
#1  inr.ruhep
1 rt2
1 rt3
```

ip a result

```
2: enp9s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:5e:d3:01:84:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.36/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp9s0
       valid_lft 9272sec preferred_lft 9272sec
    inet6 2403:6200:89a6:d09d:5606:aae2:c339:9eb1/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 581671sec preferred_lft 62705sec
    inet6 2403:6200:89a6:d09d:d5ac:2515:913e:e2be/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 863871sec preferred_lft 431871sec
    inet6 fe80::272a:26bd:9d12:e881/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp8s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:5e:d3:01:84:ed brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.101/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp8s0
       valid_lft 63271sec preferred_lft 63271sec
    inet6 fe80::b875:1df4:ff5e:9f09/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9c:53:22:48:77:19 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp10s0
    inet 192.168.1.48/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft 82853sec preferred_lft 82853sec
    inet6 fe80::8276:83ab:72d6:1287/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comparing 3 interfaces when uploading with rclone.
First one going through enp9s0 without adding --bind option so the connection gone through default line, this one doesnt have problem

```
money@money:~$ rclone move --verbose --transfers 2 --checkers 6 --bwlimit 1G --contimeout 120s --timeout 600s --retries 6 --low-level-retries 20 --buffer-size 128M --drive-chunk-size 128M --stats 1s /media/cache/vipx3 up:
2023/03/11 18:31:15 INFO  : Starting bandwidth limiter at 1Gi Byte/s
2023/03/11 18:31:16 INFO  : 
Transferred:              0 B / 74.568 GiB, 0%, 0 B/s, ETA -
Checks:                 0 / 1, 0%
Transferred:            0 / 1, 0%
Elapsed time:         1.0s
Checking:

Transferring:
 * plot-k32-c7-2023-03-11…8a61bb6c66fc76752.plot:  0% /74.568Gi, 0/s, -

2023/03/11 18:31:18 INFO  : 
Transferred:       52.871 MiB / 74.568 GiB, 0%, 20.327 MiB/s, ETA 1h2m33s
Checks:                 0 / 1, 0%
Transferred:            0 / 1, 0%
Elapsed time:         3.0s
Checking:

Transferring:
 * plot-k32-c7-2023-03-11…8a61bb6c66fc76752.plot:  0% /74.568Gi, 20.327Mi/s, 1h2m33s
```

This one going through enp8s0 (192.168.0.101) also gone through after added the ip route rule mentioned eariler

```
money@money:~$ rclone move --bind 192.168.0.101 --verbose --transfers 2 --checkers 6 --bwlimit 1G --contimeout 120s --timeout 600s --retries 6 --low-level-retries 20 --buffer-size 128M --drive-chunk-size 128M --stats 1s /media/cache/vipx3 up:
2023/03/11 18:28:39 INFO  : Starting bandwidth limiter at 1Gi Byte/s
2023/03/11 18:28:40 INFO  : 
Transferred:              0 B / 74.568 GiB, 0%, 0 B/s, ETA -
Checks:                 0 / 1, 0%
Transferred:            0 / 1, 0%
Elapsed time:         1.0s
Checking:

Transferring:
 * plot-k32-c7-2023-03-11…8a61bb6c66fc76752.plot:  0% /74.568Gi, 0/s, -

2023/03/11 18:28:42 INFO  : 
Transferred:       51.184 MiB / 74.568 GiB, 0%, 21.965 MiB/s, ETA 57m54s
Checks:                 0 / 1, 0%
Transferred:            0 / 1, 0%
Elapsed time:         3.0s
Checking:

Transferring:
 * plot-k32-c7-2023-03-11…8a61bb6c66fc76752.plot:  0% /74.568Gi, 21.965Mi/s, 57m54s
```

This is the last network interface (eno1) I added which couldnt upload right now

```
money@money:~$ rclone move --bind 192.168.1.48 --verbose --transfers 2 --checkers 6 --bwlimit 1G --contimeout 120s --timeout 600s --retries 6 --low-level-retries 20 --buffer-size 128M --drive-chunk-size 128M --stats 1s /media/cache/vipx3 up:
2023/03/11 18:27:52 INFO  : Starting bandwidth limiter at 1Gi Byte/s
2023/03/11 18:27:53 INFO  : 
Transferred:              0 B / 0 B, -, 0 B/s, ETA -
Elapsed time:         1.0s

2023/03/11 18:27:54 INFO  : 
Transferred:              0 B / 0 B, -, 0 B/s, ETA -
Elapsed time:         2.0s

2023/03/11 18:27:55 INFO  : 
Transferred:              0 B / 0 B, -, 0 B/s, ETA -
Elapsed time:         3.0s

2023/03/11 18:27:56 INFO  : 
Transferred:              0 B / 0 B, -, 0 B/s, ETA -
Elapsed time:         4.0s
```

How do I make eno1 traffic going through its own gateway like enp8s0? This line has its own router connected to its own separated ISP. Now it seems to be sharing 192.168.1.1 with enp9s0

Comment: it's not clear what you mean with "separate"; by default, network interfaces have nothing to do with each other. So, I'm probably not understanding the problem here. What is it, that you need to achieve?

Comment: They are sharing the traffic thats the problem

Comment: Please don't answer in comments, [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/739403/edit) your question instead to keep the relevant info available. "Sharing the traffic" isn't really any clearer. Repeating my request from your previous question: please add the output of `ip route`. Also it's still not clear what exactly are you trying to achieve here. `eno1` and `enp9s0` having an IP on the same address range is a very easy way to introduce traffic forwarding problems - you shouldn't have more than 1 IP interface to a range without some kind of link aggregation or prioritization.

Comment: ok added ip route result

Comment: Thanks! So, what do you *want* to happen? Which traffic  *should* go where? That's what I'm unclear about.

Comment: Ok I fixed the question. Hope its understandable now.

Comment: You've got route to 192.168.1.0/24 on `enp9s0` with metric 100, and on `eno0` with metric 103; and both have next-hop router 192.168.1.1. Lower metric takes precedence. What can you expect? Move `eno0` to a different subnet, for example 192.168.2.0/24 with next-hop router in the same network and see what happens.

Comment: Did that. Couldnt even curl; curl --interface eno1 ifconfig.me
curl: (7) Failed to connect to ifconfig.me port 80 after 3069 ms: No route to host

Comment: route -n result
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     102    0        0 enp8s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp9s0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     103    0        0 eno1

Comment: Please don't put these in comments, put them in the question, and please put only relevant info - what are you trying to show with those `rsync` outputs? To me this seems a clear routing issue, but I can't make sense of it as you're not explaining what exactly is the end goal here. This looks like an XY problem - can you please clarify what exactly are you striving to accomplish? What traffic to where is supposed to go through which interface? How's the system (or us) supposed to identify it? Why do you have 3 default routes configured?

Comment: I show rclone output so u can see that eno1 doesnt connect properly.  I want to know how do I make eno1 traffic going through its own gateway like enp8s0? This line has its own router connected to its own separated ISP. Now it seems to be sharing 192.168.1.1 with enp9s0. When I put eno1 to 192.168.2.0 it completely disconnected from internet

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by accessing the router of eno1 while had the LAN cable of enp9s0 removed since they shared 192.168.1.1 then changed its ip to 192.168.2.1
I then add these lines

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev enp8s0 src 192.168.0.101 table rt2
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp8s0 table rt2
sudo ip rule add from 192.168.0.101/32 table rt2
sudo ip rule add to 192.168.0.101/32 table rt2
```

I may have messed up during the struggling so enp8s0 came up disabled on every reboot
Don't know how to fix this yet, I even add crontrab of `sudo ifconfig enp8s0 up` but still it doesnt come at startup
I ended up having to enable it via gui, which worked

Then I add this

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 dev eno1 src 192.168.2.36 table rt1
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.2.1 dev eno1 table rt1
sudo ip rule add from 192.168.2.36/32 table rt1
sudo ip rule add to 192.168.2.36/32 table rt1
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.2.1 metric 101 dev eno1
```

ip rule result

```
0:  from all lookup local
32756:  from all to 192.168.0.101 lookup rt2
32757:  from 192.168.0.101 lookup rt2
32758:  from all to 192.168.2.36 lookup rt1
32759:  from 192.168.2.36 lookup rt1
32760:  from all to 192.168.0.101 lookup rt2
32761:  from 192.168.0.101 lookup rt2
32762:  from all to 192.168.0.101 lookup rt2
32763:  from 192.168.0.101 lookup rt2
32764:  from all to 192.168.2.36 lookup rt1
32765:  from 192.168.2.36 lookup rt1
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

here is ip route list

```
money@money:~$ ip route list table rt2
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp8s0 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp8s0 scope link src 192.168.0.101 
money@money:~$ ip route list table rt1
default via 192.168.2.1 dev eno1 
192.168.2.0/24 dev eno1 scope link src 192.168.2.36
```

Then I noticed that enp9s0 isnt in use when i run nload -m
so I added

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev enp9s0 src 192.168.1.36 table rt3
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp9s0 table rt3
sudo ip rule add from 192.168.1.36/32 table rt3
sudo ip rule add to 192.168.1.36/32 table rt3
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 metric 100 dev enp8s0
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 metric 101 dev enp9s0
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.2.1 metric 102 dev eno1
```

Now things work as intended

Comment: Toldyaso, didn't I? :-)

Comment: yeah thanks a lot